# MySQL Scheduler on update

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to let the scheduler "hear" for an update of a specific table? E.g. I have 2 tables, t1 and t2, and I update a row in t1, I would like to run an update in t2, right after it.

Comment: Trigger is what you looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use trigger for update your secon table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name  
AFTER UPDATE ON t1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   -- variable declarations

   -- trigger code

END;
```

You can see examples on this [website](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php)